# I want to calculate MTD, YTD, WTD according to fiscal calendar in power bi

Tags: powerbi

The issue is I want to display MTD, WTD, QTD sales according to fiscal calendar for example :- If i selected date 3/9/2017 then MTD should include sales during 2/23/2017 to 3/8/2017 in power bi report.

Is there any formula to get MTD in fiscal calendar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this article](http://www.sqlbi.com/articles/week-based-time-intelligence-in-dax/) which walks through the DAX measures you need. Note `Iso QTD` for example:

```
Iso QTD :=
IF (
    HASONEVALUE ( Dates[ISO Year] )
        && HASONEVALUE (Dates[ISO Quarter] ),
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Sales[Sales Amount] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( Dates ),
            Dates[ISO Year] = VALUES ( Dates[ISO Year] )
                && Dates[ISO Quarter] = VALUES ( Dates[ISO Quarter] )
                && Dates[Date] <= MAX ( Dates[Date] )
        )
    ),
    BLANK ()
)
```